# Multiple template in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In one of my application I integrated a codeigniter template using HOOKS method... Its working pretty well ... The hooks/ template will call in Controllers Constructor .. 
the 'default.php' is located in views folder ...

But I need 2 templates for my proj .. Can any one help me how to handle this ?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the 'Themes' library... each theme has its own folder inside the views folder...and its called like this : 1st line is template 2nd line is the page
$this->themes->set_theme('theme');
$this->themes->set_template('template')

then in your controller its invoked using: $this->themes->view('view');

simple insert a {page_content} tag into your template where you want to insert the page code. 
It may still be available on the CI wiki.